# use NCU with tensorRT, but got No kernels were profiled

Tags: nsight, tensorrt, nsight-compute

`ncu -o ./data/"$output" --metrics \ gpu__time_duration.sum,lts__t_sectors.avg.pct_of_peak_sustained_elapsed \ trtexec --loadEngine=../"$engine" --shapes=actual_input_1:1x"$shape" --avgRuns=1 --warmUp=0 --duration=0`

I don't get any detail info of CUDA kernel, the error message is `No kernels were profiled`
and it is no use when I add `--target-processes all`.
I want to get the detail message of CUDA kernel runtime.